# SCCM cannot connect to SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, sccm, system-center

I'm trying to install SCCM on my machine, but for some reason, I get this error:

[image]

I think I've tried everything listed in the tutorials...

- I restarted my SQL-service
- My account is a sysadmin
- I'm not using Dynamic ports
- I've changed the default port to 1433 (the default one)
- I've enables `named pipes`

But still no result... Any more ideas?

Here is my log:
[image]

Comment: Can you connect using the exact same SQL server settings in management studio?  When you say your account is a sysadmin, you mean your SQL login on that server has the sysadmin SQL role, right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that there are no firewall / network connectivity issues by running `telnet mydb-server 1433`?

Comment: I haven't set up a firewall. Should I run this commend in Console?

Comment: 1) "Have not set up a firewall". Generally, Windows has one on my default. "Run from console" Yes, run it from the console. If it works, the console will just sort of go blank. If it doesn't you will see `Connecting to my-db-server...` and eventually `Could not open connection the host, on port 1433: Connect failed`

Comment: I meant I've turned off the firewall. My colleague just told me the `telnet` commando had been cancelled in Server 2008 (and Windows 7), so do you have an alternative maybe?

Comment: Install it from the Service manager, Server Manager :: Add Features :: Telnet Client

Comment: Ok, can you deduct some useful information from my logs maybe?